# Why doesn't this attempt to make a consistent and complete axiomatic system work?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Start off with ZFC. Let $A_0$ be some statement independent of ZFC, and let ZFC+$A_0$ be denoted as ZFC$_0$. Now let $A_1$ be a statement independent of ZFC$_0$, and let ZFC$_1$ denote ZFC$_0$+$A_1$. Continue this process indefinitely, defining ZFC$_n$ for all $n\in\omega$. Then we can define ZFC$_\omega$ as ZFC+$A_0$+$A_1$+.... We can then define ZFC$_{\omega+1}$ to be ZFC$_{\omega}$ plus some axiom independent of ZFC$_{\omega}$ , and we can keep going. Eventually, this process should terminate at some $\alpha < \omega_1$, since there are only countably many statements independent of ZFC.

It seems that ZFC$_\alpha$ is consistent (relative to ZFC), since it is obtained by adding axioms which do not contradict previous axioms. Further, ZFC$_{\alpha}$ seems to be complete, since if it weren't and if there were some statement $B$ independent of ZFC$_{\alpha}$  , then the above sequence would not have actually terminated at $\alpha$.

Obviously, though, there is no relatively consistent and complete extension of ZFC if ZFC is consistent. So, where has this construction of ZFC$_{\alpha}$ gone wrong?

Comment: It hasn't gone wrong anywhere. Assume ZFC is consistent and let $M\models$ ZFC. Then the first order theory of $M$ is consistent (obviously) and complete (obviously). Gödel's theorems have another hypothesis on the theory, which is very important, and it's related to how it's computable

Comment: (By the way, what you have shown by transfinite induction can as easily be proved through Zorn's lemma: for any consistent theory $T$, there exists a complete consistent theory $T'$ with $T\subset T'$)

Comment: What Max said.  Find an actual statement of Gödel's incompleteness theorem, and see why your last paragraph is wrong.

Comment: Here's a nice short proof of Godel's first incompleteness theorem using Turing machines that sheds some light on why $T$ is restricted to recursive theories: https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=710